# JW Player with Cloudfront on iOS not working

Tags: iphone, ios, html5-video, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having an issue using JW Player 5.4 with Amazon Cloudfront.  I am using the JW Player Javascript Embed method to fall back to an HTML5 player on iOS.  This is working great, except sometimes the videos don't load properly from Cloudfront.  The player appears with a disabled play button.

The strange thing is that this seems to happen sporadically.  We are almost getting a 50/50 chance now.  I've set up a page where I have two players loading the exact same video file.  The top is loading from the local server, while the bottom from Cloudfront.

http://dj.jomrx.com/video/

If you view this page on an iPhone (4 in my tests), the top player always works correctly.  However the bottom has the issue described above.  If you refresh a bunch of times you'll (hopefully) see what I am experiencing.

Someone suggested that the loading of the video metadata is timing out.  However I thought Cloudfront was supposed to be fast as a CDN and wouldn't expect a timeout / latency issue.  Any other ideas on what might be causing the issue?  I've searched and searched but haven't found any good results yet.

Thanks a bunch!

More info (JW Player support topic): http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/17781/video-on-iphone-issue-flash-player-with-html5-fallback/

Update: Looks like this might not be an issue with JW Player. Same issue with hard-coded HTML5 video tags. http://dj.jomrx.com/video/index2.php

**Update 2:** After some help from AWS Premium Support, it looks like the issue was HTTPS.  I don't know many of the technical details and I'm not sure why, but apparently AWS says that Mobile Safari is "sometimes" rejecting the SSL certificated served by Cloudfront.  We switched to just regular HTTP and everything is fine now.

Comment: We're also experiencing severe problems with video served to iPads over Cloudfront. We're using http progressive downloads and see that latency before the video starts is very long, and the download speed is very slow. Doing wget against the same URL starts immediately and is able to saturate our downlink. It looks like Cloudfront can serve some user agents more quickly than others.